# Which version of TensorFlow.js is compatible with models trained in TensorFlow 1.12.0 (Python)?

Tags: python, tensorflow, tensorflow.js

I need to convert models trained in TensorFlow 1.12.0 Python into that of TensorFlow.js. What version of tf.js and tf.js converter is compatible with it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have not mentioned in which format you are saving your model in TensorFlow 1.12. I would recommend to make use of saved model format to save your model. If you use saved models, you can use the latest versions of tf.js and tf.js converters. Same is the case for keras h5 model as well.

However, if you save it in form of `pb` files, you will have to use tf.js version of 0.15 and tf.js converter of 0.8.6